# Ravendb 4 - Create Index Programmatically

Tags: ravendb, ravendb4

How to add a index to specific database in RavenDb 4. I see the function

`new SearchableIndex().Execute(_documentStore)`;

How to specify the database, without setting the default database as part of document store initialization. I wish to pass the database name as parameter.

Comment: One way is to set .Database property _documentStore. Not sure if thats the best way to do it. But it works.

Comment: You have to document store. You could accept a database name parameter in your own function, then create a document store with that database and execute the index against that document store.

Answer (score 1):

You set the database for the `DocumentStore` using the `Database` property. When initializing, do it like this:

```
var _documentStore = new DocumentStore
{
    Urls = new[] { "http://localhost:8080" },
    Database = "databaseName"
};

new SearchableIndex().Execute(_documentStore);
```